# Gmail's "Show trimmed content" - is there a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: gmail, keyboard-shortcuts

So far I like the "new compose experience" with one exception: I always want to "Show trimmed content" when replying.

Is there a keyboard shortcut for that? I haven't been able to find one, if there is.

Any other way to make 'trimmed content' always appear?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I noticed that if you just hit the down arrow followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> then the trimmed content is shown. Hitting the down arrow highlights the "..." reflecting the trimmed content, then hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> has the same effect as clicking on it.

Comment: This is better than anything I had come up with. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As a sort of workaround, if you **select-all** the text (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) as you start composing, Gmail will unveil the trimmed text.

As a side note, as a **Thunderbird** user I like its *quote-only-highlighted-text* feature, and it seems it can be enabled in *Gmail* → *Settings* → *Lab* as well—read [here](http://email.about.com/od/gmailtips/qt/et_quote_select.htm).

Answer (score 1):

[Trimless for Gmail](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/trimless-for-google-mail/niepjjjfafhadmfdminbckmciijcaagc/details) Chrome extension does the trick to solve the problem for Chrome users

> #### Automatically shows trimmed content in Google Mail™.
>
> Expands trimmed parts, removes "Show trimmed content" buttons, sets trimmed text's color to light gray and indents it to the right. Restores clipped messages as well. You can switch it on and off by simply clicking the scissors icon in the address bar. The color and the size of indentation are fully customizable.